.NET 8 Identity Api Endpoints validate generated token from another service
I have an authentication service developed with .NET 8 and easy implemented authentication API endpoints.
I can take the token and I want to use this token for my customer service to validate this token. But I couldn't pass this step. I am getting invalid token error all the time. And I don't know how to specify token options.
I based my code on this article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-with-identity-in-dotnet-8/
My authentication service's program.cs looks like this:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDevDb"),
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Auth.Api"));
    });

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

I tried token provider on another service

I also followed the blog you shared to create a new .net 8 web api project. And I also followed this section. Per my understanding, .net 8 improves the asp.net core identity ability in web api so that it provides an alternative to the cookie option for clients that can't use cookies. Therefore, the token and how to validate the token shall all be managed by the API side and if we already followed the blog to integrate identity, everything shall be ready.
This is my Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
//    .AddIdentityCookies();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
    options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppDb"));
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.MapIdentityApi<MyUser>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

The only diffience is that I comment .AddIdentityCookies(); but add .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme); so that I can get the access token and refresh token as the response of the login endpoint.
I also created another API controller like this:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public TestController(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        var Books = new List<Book>()
                {
                    new Book { Title = "Let us C",Id=1},
                    new Book { Title = "Let us C++",Id=2},
                    new Book { Title = "Let us C#",Id=3}
                };
        _dbContext.Books.AddRange(Books);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return Ok("good");
    }
}

Just like what you see, it has [Authorize] attribtue so that I need a credential to call this API. In the current configuration. If I don't add Bearer token into request header, I will get 401 error. If I add the token I get from login response, it will work.


